# General SQL error when accessing TDatabase on C: drive, but not on other drives

Tags: sql, delphi, bde

I have a Delphi program with a piece of code like this:

```
var
    FDatabase         : TDatabase;
...
(create and configure Fdatabase)
...
FDatabase.Connected := True;
```

On most machines in runs without problems, but for some win7 machines I get the error:

'Unknown database.
Unable to complete network request to host "127.0.0.1".
Failed to establish a connection.
No connection could be made because
General SQL error
the target machine actively refused it.'

This only happens when the program is run from the C: drive, e.g. from the installation path C:\Program Files(x86)..., or anywhere else on the C: drive. If I copy the entire installation folder to another drive, it runs fine.

My guess would be that it has something to do with UAC. It tried running as admin from the C: drive without luck.

Comment: This should be on stackoverflow. Flagged the question

Comment: What database? Is the database running on the local machine? If it's an embedded database, or an .exe in your program folder, it may not have started because it couldn't write directly to C:\Program Files (which it shouldn't be doing anyway).

Comment: it would be helpful to see the actual code for `(create and configure FDatabase)` - this is probably the most important part, why would you not show us the code that isn't working?

Comment: which is Delphi version (please edit the question and add proper TAG below the text) ? which SQL server is used (please edit the question and add proper TAG below the text) and what is the connection string ? BDE is deprecated and non-supported (especially on Vista and later, especially on 64-bit Win, so you're twice in "risk zone"). Try to find some decent DB connection components instead of BDE.

Comment: "(create and configure Fdatabase)" is critical information and you concealed it like we're all telepathic able to jump into your head and see with your eyes. That alas is not so. http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise